# Closed form of solution of functional equation

Tags: power-series, functional-equations

Consider the functional equation

$f(x)+f(\frac{x^2}{2})=x \mspace{10mu},\mspace{10mu}0<x<2$  .

$x\mapsto \frac{x^2}{2}$

$f(x)+f(\frac{x^2}{2})=x$

$f(\frac{x^2}{2})+f(\frac{x^4}{8})=\frac{x^2}{2}$

$f(\frac{x^4}{8})+f(\frac{x^8}{2^7})=\frac{x^4}{2^4}$  ...

$f(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{16}...=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{(n+1)}(x/2)^{(2^n)} $

Can one get closed form of the series?

Comment: Long story short, **no**.

Comment: Why? It's important.

Comment: Because it's a [lacunary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function), and they are just what they are.